# C++ Casting the double result of the pow function to an integer

Tags: c++, casting

I have been trying to use this code:

```
if (iteration % pow(256.0, 7) == 0) {
```

in one of my programs, but the error console says:

> error C2297: '%' : illegal, right operand has type 'double'

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state in your title, the answer is to cast the result to an integer:

```
if (iteration % static_cast<int>(pow(256.0, 7)) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `pow(256.0, 7)` is representable as an integer you should probably just define it as an appropriate const, e.g.

```
const int64_t pow_256_7 = 1LL << (8 * 7);  // 256^7
```

and then do the test like this:

```
if ((iteration % pow_256_7) == 0)
```

Comment: It's representable as an integer but probably not an `int`, so either `1` or `8*7` should be cast to `int64_t` or an appropriate suffix used.

Comment: The initializer should be 1ULL << (8 * 7) to avoid overflow when `int` is smaller than 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
iteration % pow(256.0, 7)
```

Here `pow` returns `double`. But `%` *cannot* be applied on `double` (or `float`) types.

`%` can be applied only on intergral types such as `int`, `short`, `char`, etc.

> How can I get around this error?

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you can do this:

```
iteration % static_cast<__int64>(pow(256.0, 7))
```

Or simply this:

```
const __int64 value = 256ULL * 256 *256 *256 *256 *256 *256;

if ( iteration % value  == 0 )
```

Comment: Is there a way of casting the value returned by pow to an integer?

Comment: I believe that `pow()` with casting *may* be actually faster than that multiplication. Not to mention it *will* be more readable. In any case, compiler will optimize that.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Why do you believe that? The compiler will do the multiplication at the compile time itself, no?

Comment: The multiplication can overflow when `int` doesn't hold 64 bits. Change the first `256` to `256ULL`.

Comment: @Nawaz: ah, yes. But it should do the same for `pow(256, 7)` :P.

Comment: @MichałGórny: `pow` is not defined with `constexpr`. The compiler will not evaluate it at compile-time. (also, even if it does, why would it make *"faster"*?).

Comment: @Nawaz: I agreed with you already. I just considered run-time calculation.